# is it possible pinging through nat from outside the nat inside?

Tags: echo, ping, nat

is it possible to send an echo-request to a host set behind nat
after. all the echo-request doesn't hold a port for the destination host so if there are several hosts using the same external ip address how will the nat be able to forward the echo-request to a specific host

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most modern NAT/packet filtering implementations are stateful. That means they have a wider concept of the word `connection` than the older stateless variants. That allows them to handle more complex protocols that use additional connections (e.g. FTP), as well as connection-less protocols like [ICMP](http://www.faqs.org/docs/iptables/icmpconnections.html).

In the case of ICMP packets, `echo` requests contain an `ID` field that is preserved in the reply. While its 16 bits are somewhat restrictive, it allows in conjuction with the source IP address from the IP header to have a reasonably high confidence on which `echo` request each reply corresponds to.

EDIT:

As for targeting specific hosts behind a NAT implementation, that is not generally possible. You *might* be able to:

- Redirect all ICMP traffic to one internal host to monitor that one host only.
- Use the "pad" data bytes of the `echo` request packet to provide some kind of host identifier. For example, the `-p` option of `ping` on some Linux systems allows setting that field. This is by no means standard, though.

In general, NAT is supposed to hide the hosts behind it from the world, with the exception of any forwarded IP connections.

Comment: yes, this will solve an outgoing echo request where the nat table is able to create a mapping between the sender's internal ip address and the echo message that was sent. however i was asking about a case where you want to ping a certain host which is set behind nat. in this case how will it be possible to differ one host from another?